# Quantlib-SWIG for Python error, missing Quantlib/quantlib_wrap.cpp on MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I downloaded Qauntlib-SWIG v1.9 from Sourceforge, also tried github `master` branch, followed instructions on the [official page](http://quantlib.org/install/macosx-python.shtml), but in both cases I'm left with the following error message.

I'm running `MacOS Sierra` / `Python 3.6` / `boost` version 1.64.0_1, `gcc` version below. I installed `quantlib` v1.9.2 with `Homebrew`.

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I suspect the error is caused by the first statement below: `python -c++ ...` It doesn't seem to be a valid flag for python, which gave the error message (tried `python -c++` in command prompt, got the same error).

Any idea how / where this flag came from? Thank you.

Error message:

```
(py36) me:QuantLib-SWIG $ make -C Python
python -c++ -modern -outdir QuantLib \
            -o QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp ../SWIG/quantlib.i
  File "<string>", line 1
    ++
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make: [QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp] Error 1 (ignored)
python -c++ -modern -outdir QuantLib \
            -o QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp ../SWIG/quantlib.i
  File "<string>", line 1
    ++
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make: [QuantLib/QuantLib.py] Error 1 (ignored)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
python -c++ -modern -outdir QuantLib \
            -o QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp ../SWIG/quantlib.i
  File "<string>", line 1
    ++
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[1]: [QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp] Error 1 (ignored)
python -c++ -modern -outdir QuantLib \
            -o QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp ../SWIG/quantlib.i
  File "<string>", line 1
    ++
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[1]: [QuantLib/QuantLib.py] Error 1 (ignored)
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" /Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
file QuantLib/QuantLib.py (for module QuantLib.QuantLib) not found
file QuantLib/QuantLib.py (for module QuantLib.QuantLib) not found
running build_ext
building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/include/python3.6m -I/usr/local/Cellar/quantlib/1.9.2/include -c QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.o -Wno-unused -O2 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make[1]: *** [.build-stamp] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
(py36) me:QuantLib-SWIG $
```

Comment: gcc doesn't compile C++... g++ does...

Comment: this is not related to g++.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why this was happening. Grepped the Makefile. If fact it was looking for SWIG. So a `brew install swig` resolved this issue.

Even though the official installation webpage said `swig` was not required, it was required in the end.

Comment: Hmm, no, it's not required.  `quantlib_wrap.cpp` is included in the release (you can download it again and check).  If you're cloning the code from GitHub, then yes, you'll need SWIG.  What might have happened is that a `make clean` also deleted the wrappers. We might have to add something about that in the instructions.  Anyway, glad it worked in the end.